# Prefereable air intake temperature for condensor-typed tumble dryer

Tags: dryer, condensation, laundry

I have one of those tumble dryers with a condensor - it sucks air from the room with a fan, passes the air through the inside of a 'radiator' like apparatus (as to 'cool' it), and then straight into the drum chamber. from the drum chamber the (warm) air with moist passes through the external side of the radiator, and then condensation occurs.

As the air (from the room) intake is responsible for the 'cooling' of the radiator, would it be better if the room temperature will be a bit cool, as to increase the cooling effect of the radiator?
As a result of the tumble dryers work, The room gets very warm, which causes the air intake temperature to increase greatly.

On the downside, cooling the outside air means the tumble dryer will have to invest more energy in warming it again.

So what would be better:

1) Leave everything as is - let the tumble dryer suck the warm air from the room, thus making it use less energy for heating up the air, but more time to work as condensation is less efficient

2) Turn on the air conditioner in the room - let the tumble dryer suck the cooler air from the room, thus making it more efficient (condensation wise), but make it use more energy to heat up the air

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way I understand them, condenser type dryers recycle the air rather than using a continuous supply of ambient air.

The air in the drum is passed across the heat exchanger to dehumidify it, then it is routed back into the drum. The heat exchanger is not used as an intake air pre-heater, it is solely for the purpose of dehumidification. Heat is transferred from the recycled hot air to the atmosphere, moisture is collected or drained.

If your's works differently and uses ambient air as a continuous source of "drying air", and the dehumidified exhaust is directed to the outside space (your living quarters), then the benefit of cooling it to provide for more efficient dehumidification would likely be outweighed by the need to heat it more for effective drying, since you did not complain about excess humidity conditions in your living space.

Either way, it is likely that significant engineering was involved in the design of the unit and the operating manual likely gives parameters for optimal performance conditions. I would say that unless directed to otherwise in the manual, any endeavours to alter the temperature of ambient air would provide minimal if any tangible benefit.